# Confused on example code from my c programming book

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

im confused about the purpose of adding 48 to the output of ((num >> 15 - i) & 0x0001)

```
/* Convert fixed 16-bit integer to binary digit string.
         Pre      num contains integral value to be converted
                     bitStr is a pointer to variable for bit string
         Post    bit string stored in str
*/

void bin16 (uint16_t num, char* bitStr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        bitStr[i] = (char) ((num >> 15 - i) & 0x0001) + 48;

    return;
}// end of bin16
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit lost. This is my understanding, could you/someone correct my errors. The statement num  >> 15 - i; where i is 0 on the first iteration, num then receives a right shift for 15 and then a bit by bit comparison using and logic. So if the first bit from num is 1 then the statement is parsed to char and stored in bitStr, else the first bit is zero so the statement is false, & returns 0 and a zero is stored in bitStr. So why are we adding the char '0' to the statement. I guess I don't understand how it's being used to convert 1 and 0 to '1' and '0'. I thought the statemen

Answer (score 2):

bitStr is a string. You need to convert integer numbers to char to put correct value in the string. That's why 48 is added. It's equivalent to adding `'0'`.  48 is the ASCII value of `'0'`.

It's similar as writing this -

```
void bin16 (uint16_t num, char* bitStr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        bitStr[i] = (char) ((num >> 15 - i) & 0x0001) + '0';
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 48 is the ASCII value for the character '0'.  In this situation it is being used to convert between the numbers 0 & 1 and the characters '0' & '1'

`bin16()` could have also been written:

```
void bin16 (uint16_t num, char *bitStr) {

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        bitStr[i] = (char) ((num >> 15 - i) & 0x0001) + '0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit lost. This is my understanding, could you/someone correct my errors. The statement num  >> 15 - i; where i is 0 on the first iteration, num then receives a right shift for 15 and then a bit by bit comparison using and logic. So if the first bit from num is 1 then the statement is parsed to char and stored in bitStr, else the first bit is zero so the statement is false, & returns 0 and a zero is stored in bitStr. So why are we adding the char '0' to the statement. I guess I don't understand how it's being used to convert 1 and 0 to '1' and '0'. I thought the statemen

Comment: I thought the statement  (char) (some int value ) was taking care of the conversion.

Comment: @BrienSmarandache, a notation like `(char)` in this situation is about telling the compiler you know that there is a potentional loss of bits but you, the programmer, have it under control -- it doesn't do anything to the data.  The numbers 0 and 1 are ASCII NUL (null) and SOH (start of heading), non-printing control characters.  What you want are ASCII 48, the printed number '0' and 49, the printed number '1'.  Do `man ascii` on Unix for the table of values.  The addition of '0' (aka 48) does this conversion from decimal number to ASCII digit.